# Primefaces - Jquery hotkey works only once when the focus is in input field

Tags: jquery, primefaces, hotkeys

Due to the limitations of primefaces hotkey, I have put the below jquery script [(script source)](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=22805) to make the hotkeys work when the focus is on input fields. But it works only once when the page loads for the first time. If tried after any AJAX calls it doesn't work. I have a master template which has the head and body tags;all the xhtml files are wrapped within that. Below code is on specific XHTML where hotkey is needed. When clicked outside the input fields hotkey works perfectly. Is there a way to make it work within input fields?

```
<ui:define name="pageJS">       
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        $(function() {$(':input').bind('keydown', 'ctrl+shift+v', function(){saveWidgetVar.jq.click();;return false;});});
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
</ui:define>
```

next line is wrapped within a panelgroup.

```
<p:hotkey id="saveKey" bind="ctrl+shift+v" handler="saveWidgetVar.jq.click();" />
```

Is there a certain place where the JQuery script has to be placed?

On the side note I noticed in another blog that by changing the hotkeys options this can be achieved. following are the values suggested:

```
$.hotkeys.options.filterInputAcceptingElements = false;
$.hotkeys.options.filterTextInputs = false;
```

I'm not sure where to add this?

Answer (score 0):

I customized primefaces hotkey.js by removing the input validation; added it to my local resources; then overriding the original one by including customized file in master template. Also used the following unbind code within the for loop to avoid multiple binding.

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```

everything works great!!!